Type error: Route "src/app/api/orders/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route. "default" is not a valid Route export field
I want to find the orders in the database using Prisma using the user's email (they are signed in only through Google Provider). This is the repository - https://github.com/Jayesh-kahnani/Snatch
This is the api.
// src/app/api/order/route.ts
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import prisma from "../../../../lib/prisma";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react"; // Import getSession from next-auth/react

export default async function (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  try {
    const session = await getSession({ req }); // Get the session object from the request

    if (!session) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Unauthorized" });
    }

    if (req.method !== "GET") {
      return res.status(405).json({ error: "Method Not Allowed" });
    }

    const userId = session.user?.email; // Get the user's email from the session

    if (!userId) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "User ID not found in session" });
    }

    const orders = await prisma.post.findMany({
      where: {
        author: { email: userId }, // Filter orders by user's email
        published: true, // Filter based on your criteria
      },
      include: {
        author: { select: { name: true } },
      },
    });

    res.status(200).json({ orders });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching orders:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}


This is the Page Component:
// src/app/user-orders/page.tsx
"use client"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Post from "../ui/order-list"; // Update import path

interface Order {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  authorName: string;
}

export default function Page() {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState<Order[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOrders() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("/api/order/route"); // Fetch orders from the API endpoint
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch orders");
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setOrders(data.orders); // Set orders fetched from the API
        setLoading(false); // Set loading state to false after fetching data
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching orders:", error);
        setError("Failed to fetch orders. Please try again later."); // Set error state if fetching fails
        setLoading(false); // Set loading state to false after fetching data
      }
    }

    fetchOrders(); // Call the function to fetch orders when component mounts
  }, []);

  // Display loading message while fetching data
  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  // Display error message if fetching orders fails
  if (error) {
    return <div>{error}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto mt-8 px-4 sm:px-0 text-gray-600">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900 mb-4">Your Orders</h1>
      {/* Display message if no orders found */}
      {orders.length === 0 ? (
        <div>No orders found.</div>
      ) : (
        // Display orders if available
        <div className="flex flex-wrap">
          {orders.map((order) => (
            <Post
              key={order.id}
              id={order.id}
              title={order.title}
              content={order.content}
              authorName={order.authorName || "Unknown"}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

However, I am getting this error while deploying:
   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4
   - Environments: .env
   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types ...
Failed to compile.
src/app/api/orders/route.ts
Type error: Route "src/app/api/orders/route.ts" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route.
  "default" is not a valid Route export field.
Error: Command "npx prisma generate && next build" exited with 1


or check this image
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/assets/120279764/e6112b7f-a9d1-410e-b8f1-ac7ceced4695
this is my src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import NextAuth, { User as NextAuthUser } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

interface MyUser extends NextAuthUser {
  email: string;
  name?: string;
  // Add other user-related fields as needed
}

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  
  callbacks: {
    async signIn(params) {
      const { user } = params as { user: MyUser };

      try {
        const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: { email: user.email },
        });

        if (!existingUser) {
          // If the user is not in the database, create a new user entry
          await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
              email: user.email,
              name: user.name || "", // Ensure 'name' is a string, even if it's undefined
              // Add other user-related fields as needed
            },
          });
        }

        return true; // Continue the sign-in process
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during sign-in:", error);
        return false; // Stop the sign-in process if an error occurs
      }
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

Please help. I can't understand what seems to be the problem or the fix. I am new to Nextjs and typescript.
I was expecting to show the list of orders placed by the user who is logged in.

I think the syntax is wrong:
export default async function (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {}

try this one:
export const GET = (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {};


Now its giving me a new error:
Type error: Route "src/app/api/orders/route.ts" has an invalid "GET" export:
Type "NextApiRequest" is not a valid type for the function's first argument.
Expected "Request | NextRequest", got "NextApiRequest".

that's about the req and res params in the function. NextApiRequest and NextApiResponse are not the right types, use instead the types NextRequest and NextResponse

got it, but its now giving another error -
Argument of type '[{ req: NextRequest; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetServerSessionParams'.
Type '[{ req: NextRequest; }]' is not assignable to type '[GetServerSessionOptions]'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'req' does not exist in type 'GetServerSessionOptions'.      (I tried both getSession and getServerSession but got similar errors for both)
